# SpringBoot BasicAuthentication using RestTemplateBuilder - 401 Unauthrorised

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am developing a client that consumes 3rd party Rest api using SpringBoot RestTemplateBuilder. The API requires authentication. So I am using basic authentication to pass credentials. But it is returns 401 Unauthorized response code.

This is my first project with SpringBoot. I have tried diff ways but with same result. Any help to steer me in right direction will be helplful. Thanks!

**This is my code:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AysRestClientApplication {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AysRestClientApplication.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AysRestClientApplication.class, args);
       RestClient cl = ctx.getBean(RestClient.class);
       cl.makeCall();
   }
}
```

///////////

```
@Service
public class GetChangesMClient {

private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
private final String url = "https://sample.org/restapi"; 

  public GetChangesMClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));

    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization("username", "password").build();
    this.restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
}

public GetChangesMResponseTO execute(GetChangesMRequestTO request) {
    return this.restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, GetChangesMResponseTO.class); 

}

}

class HeaderRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

private final String headerName;
private final String headerValue;

public HeaderRequestInterceptor(String headerName, String headerValue) {
    this.headerName = headerName;
    this.headerValue = headerValue;
    System.out.println("Setting Interceptors");
}

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("intercepted");
    request.getHeaders().set(headerName, headerValue);
    return execution.execute(request, body);
}

}
```

///////////

```
@Service
public class RestClient {

@Autowired
private GetChangesMClient client;

public void makeCall(){
    RequestTO request = new RequestTO();


    ResponseTO response = this.client.execute(request);

}
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
```

**Update**
I changed my code to use interceptor to set BasicAuth and it is working now. So I am not sure why SpringBoot basicAuthenticator method doesn't work.

Interceptor Code:

```
class BasicAuthInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public BasicAuthInterceptor(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = httpRequest.getHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, encodeCredentialsForBasicAuth(username, password));

        return clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);
    }

    public static String encodeCredentialsForBasicAuth(String username, String password) {      
        return "Basic " + Base64Utils.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
    }
}
```

And then I use it like:

```
interceptors.add(new BasicAuthInterceptor("username", "pwd"));
```

I still would like to find out why my first approach did not work.